# How to remove my phone number from someone else's Twitter account?

Tags: twitter, sms

I got a new phone number, and I am receiving dozens of Twitter notifications an hour even throughout the night.

From everything I've seen texting `STOP` to the Twitter short code, which to my understanding is 40404 (that's the number the notifications are coming from) should remove my number from the old user's account.

Unfortunately, this is not working.  It is a prepaid phone, the notifications are burning through all my minutes, it is keeping me awake and distracted and I need it to stop.

I have tried adding the number to my own Twitter account, but it is blocked because someone else has it on their account.

One reason I could think of that it may not be removing with the text to the short code is that the offending account actually has a Google Voice number listed as their mobile number which is forwarding to me. (Yes, I understand this does not make sense with the previously mentioned not being able to add it to my Twitter account, but I'm desperate.) So I tried adding the number to my Google Voice account, but that did not work either.

I can't think of anything else to do.  Please help.

Followup: I just tried tweeting myself from their phone so that I could find out who it was and ask them to remove the number from their account, but it seems the tweet never went through.  Maybe the account was deactivated?

Apparently you can search Twitter users by phone number.  I tried searching by phone number and this person seems to have disabled that.

Since I'm getting no response at all from 40404 (including tweets, `STOP`, `HELP`, `START`, etc) I thought I'd try their international long code (+44 7624 801423). It did not work.  I then checked with my carrier, and they do not support international texting.  However if you are reading this for help, and your carrier does, please note that I read Twitter *requires* U.S. users to use the short code, so it probably will not work anyway.

Comment: So, you don't actually know which Twitter account this is? Have you tried searching for one of the received Tweets verbatim?

Comment: Yes, all the ones I've searched for are just tweets from different celebrates they have chosen to follow.

Comment: You're still getting these SMSs 1.5 years later, and stuck with the same phone number? Which carrier is it, and were they unwilling to block it or change your number? There are ways to block SMSs but with some you'll still pay and some won't block short codes, like Verizon's online tool. https://www.google.com/search?q=block+spam+sms

Comment: Yes, I still get these SMSs.  It is an obamaphone! (Which has nothing to do with obama, but work with me here)  They can not block the short code, and sent me a new SIM to use to change the number, but every time I call it is an hour+ on hold, so I've given up.
I actually got a freedompop phone in the mean time, which is WAY better than the obamaphone and still free, so the obamaphone now just sits on my desk connected to the charger being annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter's help pages have some info on this:

- [My email, phone number, or username is already in use](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15348)
- [How is my phone number associated with another Twitter account?](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20172029#phone-in-use)

but their only real answer for your question is this part:

- Still need help? [Contact Support](https://support.twitter.com/forms).

I suggest you do that.

Alternatively, ask your phone service provider to change your new phone number and hopefully refund the minutes used by the number's previous customer. Or maybe they can block Twitter for you.

Comment: All of the relevant forms I can find say that they do not respond to individual reports.  My issue doesn't fall under any of the options they seem to handle individually.

Comment: Since they're flooding your phone with text messages, I'd try to adapt one of their individual response issues to get through to someone who can fix it, and tell them you're going to report them for spam if they don't fix it. Then follow through on spam, including these tips: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_spam (forwarding spam messages to short code 7726 "SPAM") and these: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41123/how-do-you-block-annoying-text-message-sms-spam/

Comment: I did fill out this form: https://support.twitter.com/forms/feature_report?feature=notifications (though writing my full history in 500 chars required art) I'll give that a day and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in with phone number.
2. Click "forgot password".
3. Click "send code to phone".
4. Reset foreign account password.
5. Create new password. I used "temp01".
6. Log in.
7. Go to settings.
8. Click on "Mobile".
9. Delete phone number.
10. Log out.

Done. no more SMS from foreign accounts.

Comment: Did you read the post?  I have no idea what the account info is.

Answer (score -2):

This won't help if you do not have access to your number, but I run into this problem every time I need to create a new twitter account (for projects, for client web sites, the twitter API requires a phone) and I forget which account I put the phone number into, but...

To disconnect your number from twitter (e.g. to clear it so you can use for a new account), simply  text “stop” to 40404

Comment: Please see the second paragraph of my question and **Edited 3rd time to add**

Comment: You have a special case that IMHO only twitter can resolve. Good luck getting them to respond

Comment: Yeah, it's been fruitless.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps they were simply following celeb tweets without creating an account. Look up SMS commands for Twitter and start unfollowing each celeb as you see the tweet. You can then confirm those texts stopped by monitoring that celeb account. This will work even for non-celeb accounts and you can monitor any non-private ones. Since you aren’t getting notification texts, follow etc. and your tweet doesn’t land that’s probably what’s happened.

Comment: It seems like you did not read my post in its entirety.  I had used all the different SMS commands for Twitter that were available.  I have long since gotten rid of this number though, so it is now a non-issue for me.