# How to know Twitter accounts that linked to my phone number?

Tags: twitter

I have Twitter account linked to my phone number, every thing OK, but when I try to sign-in to Twitter using my phone number instead of email or username I get this message:

> We found more than one account with that telephone number.

How to know the other accounts linked to my phone number?

Comment: The answers on [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80892/354), although it's about a slightly different issue, may be helpful.

Comment: @ale  thanks bro, but that didn't helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I had a few Twitter (Twitter allows several accounts to be connected to the same number.) accounts with one phone number connected to the different accounts. When I tried to log in with my telephone number I also got the message

> We found more than one account with that telephone number.

I'd forgotten the username of the Twitter account I wanted to access but I knew my number was connected to that account. I knew the username of my other accounts. 
I went in to each account individually and removed my mobile number like this

> 1. Log in to your Twitter account.
> 2. Go to your Settings and privacy by
>      clicking your profile icon at the top right of the navigation bar and
>      selecting Settings and privacy from the drop-down menu.
> 3. Click on the
>      Mobile tab. Next to where your phone number is listed, click Edit.
> 4. Delete your phone number.

I then tried to logging on with my phone number again and Twitter took my to the account I'd forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

From [Twitter Help Center](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/which-is-my-mobile-phone-account):

> **How to find out which Twitter account your phone is connected to**
>
> 1. Navigate to twitter.com on a computer. This link only works if you're logged out of Twitter.
> 2. Click on the [Activate your account](https://twitter.com/account/complete) link located on the home page as shown below.
> 3. **Enter your phone number** when directed, along with the country code.
> 4. If your phone number is linked to a Twitter account, we'll send your phone a text message containing a **verification code**. Use this code to confirm that the mobile number belongs to you.
> 5. On the following page, Twitter will ask you to **complete your Twitter profile**. Your username will already be filled in. That username belongs to the same account your phone is tied to.

See these also:
[Help with an email, phone number, or username that's already in use](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/when-email-phone-number-or-usernname-is-already-in-use).
[Adding your phone number to multiple accounts](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/how-to-add-a-phone-number-to-your-account).

If this doesn't help you, contact [Twitter Support](https://help.twitter.com/en/contact-us).

Comment: thank's bro, but in these steps after I enter my phone number with country còde, I got redirect to login page. I'll try contact support team and reply to you if the issue fixed

Comment: that didn't help <\3

Comment: As of now this is the only I can help, generally this works. Lets wait if someone can offer any other solution. Try to contact Twitter support Twitter with some other account.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *this* is a workaround for you. I have a few generally inactive Twitter accounts, and only the last one (chronologically) I entered a phone number for. Maybe it's a recent thing for Twitter to require a phone number?

Anyway, I checked the notes I kept when setting them up. The phone number I used had two extra digits at the end. You know that any extra digits dialled are superfluous, so it only requires Twitter to not unreasonably limit the length of your phone number. I used phone number like this: +6141212345678 (example). If you can sign up like that, and the +43123123456 (example) is correct, then it doesn't matter about the 78.

If you have your user name and password for your other Twitter accounts then you can check when you log in. Otherwise forget about it, because they may have been from someone else, or some other people, who used to have you phone number!

That's the only reason I can think why I must have had to add extra digits to my phone number when creating the Twitter account, as I don't remember ever giving Twitter a phone number for my early accounts, although, maybe I did, as my extra digits were 05, and this was the FIFTH Twitter account I had ever created.